# Problema con rutas ASP.NET

Tags: html5, asp.net, bootstrap, url

Hice un sitio web ASP.NET (usando .NET 2.0). Use un masterpage donde coloqué un menú con bootstrap (sin usar el control menu de ASP.NET); el punto es que cada elemento de un DropDownList debe enviar a una pagina concreta; sin embargo al ingresar y dar clic en algun elemento del menú sí envía a la pagina pero cuando, estando en esa pagina, selecciono otro elemento el enlace ya no funciona porque la URL la coloca mal. Ejemplo:

1.- Clic en MenuItem1 si manda a locahost/sitioweb/subcarpeta/pagina1.aspx
2.- Estando en localhost/sitioweb/subcarpeta/pagina1.aspx se da clic en MenuItem2, la URL la pone así localhost/sitioweb/subcarpeta/subcarpeta/pagina2.aspx.

¿Como puedo resolver eso?

Acá el código:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="..\SAC\cxc_general.aspx">General</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="..\SAC\cxc_cliente.aspx">Resumen por Cliente</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="..\SAC\antsaldos.aspx">Antigüedad de Saldos</a>
```